# Jhipster Gateway Ubuntu - Blank Page Angular

Tags: java, angular, maven, jhipster

I have a Jhipster Gateway project that is showing a blank page when i run it and not the ANGULAR admin, home or login. I have tried the following commands:

```
mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-yarn -DnodeVersion=v8.11.3 -DyarnVersion=v1.9.2
mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:yarn

mvnw compile -s settings.xml
mvnw verify -s settings.xml -DskipTests

yarn global add node-gyp
npm install node-sass
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack 
yarn start
```

Nothing is working.

I am using an Ubuntu machine. The backend runs perfectly (`./mvnw clean install -s settings.xml`) as well as the front end (`yarn start`)

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DemoComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
Angular 21
syntaxError
_getDependenciesMetadata
_getTypeMetadata
getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata
_getEntryComponentMetadata
_getEntryComponentsFromProvider
_getEntryComponentsFromProvider
_getProvidersMetadata
_getProvidersMetadata
_getProvidersMetadata
_getProvidersMetadata
getNgModuleMetadata
getNgModuleMetadata
getNgModuleSummary
getNgModuleMetadata
getNgModuleMetadata
_loadModules
_compileModuleAndComponents
compileModuleAsync
compileModuleAsync
bootstrapModule
<anonymous> 634:11
<anonymous> main.bundle.js:3609
__webpack_require__ main.bundle.js:20
<anonymous> main.bundle.js:66
<anonymous> main.bundle.js:69
```

Interestingly, I can view the Swagger UI but not the angular UI

Further details:

**yarn version v1.22.4
npm 6.14.5**

```
**Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.1
@angular/cdk                 6.4.7
@angular/cli                 10.0.1
@ngtools/webpack             6.0.0
@schematics/angular          10.0.1
@schematics/update           0.1000.1
rxjs                         6.1.0
typescript                   2.7.2
webpack                      2.7.0**
```

Comment: What do you see in browser's console tab and network tab? How did you run the gateway? Your question seriously lacks some details

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I am sorry, I was frustrated and tired :D , this is the second day on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. It was due to versions of web pack in my package.json

```
{
  "name": "services",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for services",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0-10",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.1.0-8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular2-highlight-js": "^6.0.1-alpha",
    "angular2-loaders-css": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bpmn-js": "^1.3.3",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.24.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "file:node_local_patches/chartjs-plugin-annotation",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.5.3",
    "ng2-charts-x": "file:node_local_patches/ng2-charts-x",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "video.js": "^7.6.5",
    "videojs-flash": "^2.1.0",
    "webstomp-client": "1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "22.2.3",
    "@types/node": "9.4.7",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "browser-sync": "2.24.4",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.2.2",
    "cache-loader": "1.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.10",
    "exports-loader": "0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "0.4.1",
    "generator-jhipster": "5.0.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "5.2.2",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "7.0.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "2.1.1",
    "prettier": "1.11.1",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.20.3",
    "tapable": "1.0.0",
    "thread-loader": "1.1.5",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "4.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.9.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
    "webpack": "4.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.6.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.3.2"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,css,scss}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prettier:format": "yarn prettier --write 'src/**/*.{ts,css,scss}'",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run lint --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "yarn run start",
    "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
    "test": "yarn run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watch --clearCache",
    "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
    "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results.xml"
  }
}
```